# How to do symbolic spline curve fitting in C#?

Tags: c#, spline

In Maple, we can use spline() to do symbolic curve fitting. For instance, given

```
enter code here
(x1,x2,x3)=（1，2，3）and (y1,y2,y3),we can get the fitted spline function:
y=f1(y1,y2,y3)*x1+g1(y1,y2,y3)*x^2+h1(y1,y2,y3)*x^3 when 1<x<2
y=f2(y1,y2,y3)*x1+g2(y1,y2,y3)*x^2+h2(y1,y2,y3)*x^3 when 2<x<3
```

How can I achieve this in C#? Use which library?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to evaluate the interpolation as well?  What do you need a symbolic interpolation for?

Comment: I have 10 unknown Ys, but just 5 equations. I hope the curve (x,y) is cubic spline. So I want to get the symbolic form first and solve the equations next.